# Add new commit to the existing Git tag

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-svn, git-tag

I have created a Git tag as `v1.1` using

```
git tag -a v1.1 -m 'my version 1.1'
```

and I pushed that tag. Later, I made some changes related to `v1.1`. Now when I push new changes and check the git tag using 
`git describe` it is showing me `v1.1-g2dcc97`.

How can I add my new commit to the existing tag?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. A tag points to an _exact_ commit. If you make further changes based on the commit pointed to by the tag, `git describe` won't return the tag name. If you want the exact name of a tag the commit in question must be tagged.

Comment: `git describe` shows your *current* state (latest tag + commits since then, (a few digits of) the current HEAD's hash), i.e., `v1.1-g2dcc97` says "tag `v1.1`, hash for that commit is `2dcc97...`"

Comment: ``git describe`` is showing more than just the tag name.  Your tag has not been renamed.  ``git describe`` is just showing an abbreviation of the commit hash to which your tag points.

Comment: Sorry for trouble, can you please read my modifications

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can't put a new commit into an existing tag without breaking an important Git guideline: **Never(*) modify commits that you have published.**

Tags in Git aren't meant to be mutable. Once you push a tag out there, leave it alone.

You can, however, add some changes on top of `v1.1` and release something like `v1.1.1` or `v1.2`. One way of doing that would be

```bash
# Create a new branch from tag v1.1
git checkout -b newbranch v1.1

# Do some work and commit it

# Create a new tag from your work
git tag -a -m "Tag version 1.1.1, a bugfix release" v1.1.1
```

(*) Unless you have a really super special reason for doing so, and only if you completely understand the implications, and even then, don't make a habit of it.

Comment: And then `git push origin --tags` (if pushing to `origin`), to push the changes to your origin remote.

Comment: super serious warning/suggestion at the end

Comment: to push the tag to remote repo `git push origin tag_name`

e.g `git push origin v1.1.1`

Answer (score 29):

If you **absolutely** need to "move" the tag instead of creating a new one, You can do this:

**NB**: As [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris) said, make sure you have a good reason for not wanting to create a new tag because the best practice is to create a new one

**1.** Checkout the tag (a Detached HEAD)

`git checkout tag/v1.1`

**2.** Create and Checkout a branch off that tag (i.e. Branching off the tag)

`git checkout -b my-tagged-branch`

`*** do work and commit changes ***`

**3.** Push to the remote branch.

```
git push  -u origin my-tagged-branch
```

If needed merge branch into other branches that need the change (in case of a bug fix for example)

**4.** While still on `my-tagged-branch`, Delete the tag

`git tag -d v1.1`

**5.** Create the tag again: This will "move" the tag to point to your latest commit on that branch

`git tag v1.1`

**6.** Delete the tag on remote

`git push origin :v1.1`

**7.** Create the tag on remote

`git push origin v1.1`

Answer (score 4):

I think many people believe that tags mean that multiple commits can have the same tag (how tags usually work).
Like adding a tag to make a certain type of commit (ex: prod?)
Well, in git, a tag is unique to a commit.

However, if you really want to use a tag you already used before you will need to delete it from remote and local and recreate it. But you should not want to do this...

```
//remove remote tag
git push origin :tag_name

//remove tag from local
git tag -d tag_name

//add tag to latest commit
git tag tag_name

git log

git push origin tag_name
```