# Not able to commit in git tag

Tags: git, version-control

I have created a tag from a git branch named v1.0 . I need to do changes in that tag. I have check out the tag using

```
git checkout tags/v1.0
```

when I made changes I was able to commit the changes but not able to push to that created tag

Comment: when i say git {push origin tag v1.0} it says Every thing up to date

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add new commit in the existing git tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459540/add-new-commit-in-the-existing-git-tag)

Comment: @Chris thanks got it working

Answer (score 0):

There is a section on **Re-tagging** in the [git docs here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) and I think it perfectly answers your question.

**TLDR:**

1. If you did not push the tag, do the changes you want to add, commit and then tag using `-f` option. The `-f` stands for `force` and it will replace the previous tag with this new one.
2. If you pushed already, it is recommended not to use `-f` and release a new tag `v1.1`.